# Solve simple stochastic variational inequality

Tags: reference-request, differential-equations, convex-optimization, calculus-of-variations, convex-analysis

Let $Z$ be a random variable with finite mean $\mathbb E[Z]$ and let $\phi:(-\infty,\infty) \rightarrow (-\infty,\infty]$ be a convex l.s.c function which is differentiable at $z=1$ with gradient $\phi'(1)=0$.

## Question

How to find / characterize all the numbers $c\in \mathbb R$ verying the "stochastic" variational inequality
$$
\begin{split}
&1 \in \mathbb E[\partial \phi^*(Z-c)],\\
&\phi'(1) = 0.
\end{split}
$$

**N.B.:** 
Here $\phi^*(z) := \sup_t zt - \phi(t)$ defines the usual convex conjugate and
$$\partial \phi^*(z) := \{g \in \mathbb R | \phi^*(t) \ge \phi^*(z) + g(z-t)\;\forall t \in \mathbb R\}
$$
is the subdifferential of $\phi^*$ at $z$.

## Some concrete examples

**Z takes on finitely many values.**
Suppose $Z$ can only take one of $n$ distinct values $z_1,\ldots,z_n$ with probabilities $p_1,\ldots,p_n$.

Then the above problem reads:

$$
\begin{split}
&1 \in \sum_{i=1}^np_i\partial \phi^*(z_i-c),\\
&\phi'(1) = 0,
\end{split}
$$
which is just a classical variational inclusion problem. The particular case $n=1$ gives

$$
\begin{split}
&1 \in \partial \phi^*(z_1-c) \iff z_1-c \in \partial \phi(1),\\
&\phi'(1) = 0,
\end{split}
$$
giving the unique solution $c=z_1$.

**Quadratic potential.** Suppose $\phi(z) = \alpha(z-1)^2/2$, for some $\alpha > 0$.
A simple computation gives, $\phi^*(z) = \dfrac{z^2}{2\alpha} + z$, from which it follows that the unique solution for our problem is $c=\mathbb E[Z]$.